# Select the first preceding LI element

Tags: jquery

This is the fragment of my code:

```
<ul>
<li id="eur" class="na">EUR<br /><span class="orgic ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close">.</span><span class="orgic ui-icon ui-icon-help">.</span></li>
</ul>

$("span.ui-icon-help").click(function () {
   alert($(this).prevAll("li").attr("id"));
});
```

What I need is to get the id of the first

element preceding the one we click on, i.e. 2nd span with class **ui-icon-help** - it should trigger an alert "eur".

This code doesn't work and it selects the preceding span, instead of "li".

How to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$("span.ui-icon-help").click(function () {
   alert($(this).closest("li").attr("id"));
   //alert($(this).parent().attr("id"));
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/eeHcc/)

[.prevAll()](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) selects the previous sibling elements - in your case the `span.ui-icon-circle-close` and `br` elements are the previous sibling. But what you need is the ancestor elements. In your case since the `span` is the direct descendant of the target `li` you can use [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) or you can use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find the closest ancestor matching the passes selector

Answer (score 1):

try using [.parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/), like:

```
$("span.ui-icon-help").click(function () {
   alert($(this).parents("li").attr("id"));
});
```